# MYSQL select Sales list all the names even if they are not sold

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

I need to select the sale of items and the amount.

I'll use a script

```
select it.name
     , sum(sa.cash) 
  from items it 
  join sale sa 
    on it.id = sa.iditems
 where sa.time = '2020-11-10' 
 order 
    by it.nazev
```

which will list me e.g.

```
name   cash
Book   300
Mug    400
```

But I have more items that are not for sale in that day and I would also need to list them so that 0 or null is written as a sum

The result should be

```
Name   cash
Book   300
Mug    400
Soap    0
Cover   0
Sheet   0
```

Thank you

Comment: read it first https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And that query cannot generate that result.

Answer (score 2):

That's a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select it.name, coalesce(sum(sa.cash) , 0) as cash
from items it 
left join sale sa on it.id = sa.iditems and sa.time = '2020-11-10' 
group by it.name
order by it.name
```

You can also do this with a subquery:

```
select it.name,
    (select coalesce(sum(sa.cash) , 0) from sale sa where sa.iditems = it.id and sa.time = '2020-11-10') as cash
from items it
order by it.name
```